# Help for comments isn't entirely helpful

Tags: feature-request

The help for comments reads:

```
Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment.
```

But (in my browser and the one's I've tested) there's a line break after

```
[link]
```

and before

```
(http://example.com)
```

which makes it a little unclear that there should be no spaces/etc between them and that the two bits of code are related.

Can this be tidied up?

Comment: Good catch!  Looks the same to me in FF.  Might depend on screen resolution though.

Comment: @C.Ross It's resolution-independent; the help box has a set with of 434px.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Which makes actually it makes it dependent on a combination of resolution and text size. I don't see this bug right now because my text size is usually modified (due to the particular resolution and physical size of my laptop monitor).

Comment: Hm. It seems like the most reasonable course of action would be to just start the formatting tips after the colon on a whole new line. Then the link syntax should be okay on most any resolution, and all the other ones don't risk a linebreak in the middle anyway.